# How to fetch the text from each td inside of each tr and append it to a div on load

Tags: jquery, html, each, appendto

I need to fetch the text from each td inside of each tr and append it to a div on load, 
I have an element that I want to append a series of "rows" to using spans for each row,
for example: `<span class="td's class">each td's text here</span><br>` these pieces of text need to be fished out of a table further down the page.
To be appendTo() div.orderDescription all on  doc load

orderDescription Block to appended to

```
    <div class="four columns pull-left box">
        <p class="orderDescription">
            Description:<br>
          <!-- spans appended here -->  
        </p>
    </div>
```

The table to get the text from

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"> <table><thead><tr class="headerRow"><th class="item-name">Name</th><th class="item-thumb"></th><th class="item-price">Price</th><th class="item-decrement"></th><th class="item-quantity">Qty</th><th class="item-increment"></th><th class="item-total">SubTotal</th><th class="item-remove"></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-1"><td class="item-name">Fiber 1234&reg;</td><td class="item-thumb"><img width="100" src="/cb2014-II/img/products/Fiber1234.jpg"></td><td class="item-price">$55.00</td><td class="item-decrement"><a class="simpleCart_decrement" href="javascript:;"><i title="Decrease Qty" class="entypo icon-minus-circled giantText redtext"></i></a></td><td class="item-quantity">2</td><td class="item-increment"><a class="simpleCart_increment" href="javascript:;"><i title="Increase Qty" class="entypo icon-plus-circled giantText greentext"></i></a></td><td class="item-total">$110.00</td><td class="item-remove"><a class="simpleCart_remove" href="javascript:;"><i title="Remove this Item" class="entypo icon-trash giantText redtext"></i></a></td></tr><tr class="itemRow row-1 even" id="cartItem_SCI-3"><td class="item-name">Detox Diet 1234&reg;</td><td class="item-thumb"><img width="100" src="/cb2014-II/img/products/DetoxDiet1234.jpg"></td><td class="item-price">$32.95</td><td class="item-decrement"><a class="simpleCart_decrement" href="javascript:;"><i title="Decrease Qty" class="entypo icon-minus-circled giantText redtext"></i></a></td><td class="item-quantity">1</td><td class="item-increment"><a class="simpleCart_increment" href="javascript:;"><i title="Increase Qty" class="entypo icon-plus-circled giantText greentext"></i></a></td><td class="item-total">$32.95</td><td class="item-remove"><a class="simpleCart_remove" href="javascript:;"><i title="Remove this Item" class="entypo icon-trash giantText redtext"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

I have found other answers that do not seem to work. I hope this is not considered a duplicate question. I could not find the answer I need already posted.
I know this does not work but I am stumped. Please feel free to help me out on this one.

```
$("#reviewCart tbody tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td").each(function() {
    var class = ("td").attr('class');
    var txt = ("td").text();
    $("<span class='"+class+"'>"+txt+"</span>").appendTo($(".orderDescription"));
  });
});
```

Comment: what is `("td")` suppose to do?

Comment: post the html. the html you have and the html as you wish the result of your function

Comment: @ErikPhilips I was in a hurry and being lazy, the ("td") should have been $("td")

Comment: @StephenNielsen please don't put code in comments.  You can update your question as many times as needed to increase your chances of people understanding your needs and answering your question.

Comment: thanks @ErikPhilips, just noticed that, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust a lot of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reviewCart tbody tr td").each(function() {
    var myclass = $(this).attr('class');
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $("<span class='"+myclass+"'>"+txt+"</span>").appendTo(".orderDescription");
  });
});
```

`class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) don't use it.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LmjAz/)

My Html:

```
<div id="reviewCart">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test 3</td>
        <td>test 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="orderDescription">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ErikPhilips this solution does not seem to work on my page.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, the JsFiddle example works flawlessly.

Comment: I am not able to see the js fiddle My network at work is to tight. It does not make sense that it would work because your div to hold the spans is below the table in the DOM does it?

Comment: I'll update my answer with the HTML I am using for comparison.  The location of the element(s) with a class of `orderDescription` has no bearing on pretty much anything.